# After migration from magento 1 to magento 2. All customer page problem

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2.3, migration, data-migration-tool

After migrating from **M1** to **M2** everything seemed to function fine, but when I press the "**All customers**" page from backend, there is an exception.

This is what it spit out:

```
[2020-04-13 21:58:05] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config {"report_id":"b21f29b28df4c317f0498d14e0dbd03d40db342d62a38b603f94557c07d993a4","exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Config at /var/www/bla/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131)"} []
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: My first guess would be to check if all customer attributes you've migrated have their source classes created as well

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Tried deleting all entires from customer_eav_attribute table and it "worked" (some weird text in user page). So I'm guessing there are some entires in this table it is not happy with. How would I figure out which ones it would be?

Comment: Reload table once again and delete one by one.

Comment: Had the following entries: 253, 254, 259, 261, 263, 264 in the table customer_eav_attribute. After deleting 259, it worked as far as I know :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all the **attribute customers** you migrated in the **table eav_attribute**, then check whether there is something wrong with **source_model**